# Pyqt5 to interface Arduino servo ErrorType " object has no attribute 'ser'"

Tags: python, arduino, pyqt, pyqt5, pyserial

I have a problem with interfacing the Arduino. I can communicate with the Arduino with a simple program like reading the data and writing them. I have created an interface using PyQt5 to control a servo motor and I get the error:

> 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'ser'

The code I used is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import serial
import time
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow, ser):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(318, 309)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton", self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenShutter)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton_2", self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 150, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.CloseShutter)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 318, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))

    def CloseShutter(self):
        print("Shutter Closed")
        self.ser.write(int(0))



    def OpenShutter(self):
        print("Shutter Opened")
        self.ser.write(int(77))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
    ser.timeout = 1
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    if ser.isOpen() == False:
        ser.open()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow, ser)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ser` is not a member of the class so it will only exist in the context of the method, not in the context of the class.

The most recommended is not to modify the design and create a class that implements the logic, and in that class make a member of the class to the serial object. So I recommend not to modify the `Ui_MainWindow` class and restore it to the initial state.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        self.ser.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
        self.ser.timeout = 1
        self.ser.baudrate = 9600
        if self.ser.isOpen() == False:
            self.ser.open()

    def CloseShutter(self):
        print("Shutter Closed")
        self.ser.write(int(0))

    def OpenShutter(self):
        print("Shutter Opened")
        self.ser.write(int(77))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks Alot eyllanesc, it worked as you suggested :)